# How do I Write Overlapping Question and Answer Pairs to New Files?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, overlapping

I'll start this off by saying that I'm completely new to Python, and this class is the first Python class I've ever taken. I'm trying to complete an assignment and after days of trial and error, I still can't figure out how to answer this question properly. I've been given a text file called QA_Pairs.txt, and in it are question and answer pairs (so line 1 is a question, line 2 is the answer for that question, and so on for about 5000 lines). This is a portion of the file, for context:

"question Who escaped the persecution of House Stark?

answer Faceless Man

question What is Arya trained as at the House of Black and White in Braavos?

answer House Stark

question Who was the faceless man in Braavos?

answer Frey"

Some of the answers have been used to answer more than one question(for example, the answer "Tyrion" has been paired with several questions). So if the same answer or question is used more than once within the file, it should be written to the Overlapping.txt file, otherwise it should be written to unique_QA_pairs.txt.

For some more context, here is the exact way the question is written in my assignment:

1. How many QA pairs in QA_Pairs.txt? Here (q1, a1) is a pair, where q stands for question, and a for answer.
2. Are these pairs unique? For example: (q1, a1) (q1, a1) are identical and overlapping;
   (q1, a1) (q1, a2) are overlapping, and (q1, a1) (q2, a1) are overlapping as well. If not
   unique, find the overlapping pairs, and generate a unique_QA_Pairs.txt file and an
   Overlapping.txt file. The format of unique_QA_Pairs.txt and Overlapping.txt are the
   same as QA_Pairs.txt.

So my task is to create a function that takes the overlapping pairs ((q1, a1) and (q1,a2), for example)) and writes them to a new file called Overlapping.txt. All the unique pairs must be written to a new file called unique_QA_pairs.txt. Both files should have the same format as QA_Pairs.txt.

I've tried a bunch of different approaches but nothing seems to be working. This is the best I've got so far:
Overlapping_pairs()

```
file_object = "QA_Pairs.txt"

overlappedQ = []
overlappedA = [] 
uniqueQ = [] 
uniqueA =[] 

with open(file_object, 'r') as file: 
    i = 1
    for line in file: 
        if line.startswith("question"): 
            if (line[len("question"):] in uniqueQ):
                overlappedQ.append(line[len("question"):].rstrip("\n"))
                overlappedA.append(line[len("answer"):].rstrip("\n"))
            
            else: 
                uniqueQ.append(line[len("question"):].rstrip("\n"))
        if line.startswith("answer"):
            if (line[len("answer"):] in uniqueA): 
                overlappedQ.append(line[len("question"):].rstrip("\n"))
                overlappedA.append(line[len("answer"):].rstrip("\n"))
            else: 
                uniqueA.append(line[len("answer"):].rstrip("/n"))
                
if (len(overlappedA) == 0 and len(overlappedQ) == 0): 
    with open ("unique_QA_pairs.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(uniqueQ[i])
        f.write(uniqueA[i])
        file.write("\n")
else: 
    with open("Overlapping.txt", "w") as file: 
        for i in range(len(overlappedA)): 
            file.write(overlappedQ[i])
            file.write(overlappedA[i])
            file.write("\n")
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
Overlapping_pairs()
```

I know it's not great, so if there are more concise ways to do this, feel free to let me know. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "overlapping pairs"?

Comment: I've added some clarification to my question, hope this helps. My prof didn't word the assignment very well to begin with so I hope my edit makes sense

Comment: "So my task is to create a function that takes the overlapping pairs ((q1, a1) and (q1,a2), for example)) and writes them to a new file called Overlapping.txt." It sounds like you first need to determine which pairs are "overlapping".

Comment: Yes, that's where I'm having the issue. The file contains over 5000 pairs of questions and answers. So I'm trying to understand how to write a program that determines where the pairs exist.

Comment: Let's say you had 10 pairs of questions and answers on a piece of paper. How would you find the "overlapping pairs"? Describe in words the steps you would take to do it yourself.

Comment: Well visually it would be pretty easy to see. If you notice a question or answer that comes up more than once, you'd write it out onto a new piece of paper

Comment: Ok, let's add some more detail. What do you mean by "if you notice a question or answer that comes up more than once"? How can you systematically do this? What steps would you take? (Hint: let's pretend that you have two copies of the same list of questions and answers)

Comment: Okay, I'd scan each line on the piece of paper one by one. If I notice repetition somewhere down the line (i.e. the same combinations of letters and words in the same order as in a previous question/answer), I'd group those lines together into their own list.

Comment: "I'd scan each line on the piece of paper one by one" This is a good. Now give more detail about "if I notice repitition somewhere..." How can you systematically find the repetition? Remember that ultimately we want to translate this into a computer program and a computer program can't just "notice repitition". We have to define what this means in more detail.

Comment: I guess a better way to say that would be, if I notice that there is more than 1 of the same string in the list, I have to categorize that as a "repeating string".

Comment: How do you "notice that there is more than 1 of the same string in the list"? This is still too vague to turn into a computer program. What if you have two copies of the same list of questions and answers? Can you use that to systematically find duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

One narrow problem is this block of code: the opened file handle is `f` but
your last write operation tries to use `file`:

```
with open ("unique_QA_pairs.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(uniqueQ[i])
    f.write(uniqueA[i])
    file.write("\n")            # Raises an error.
```

I don't understand your description of the difference between the two output
files (`Overlapping.txt` vs `unique_QA_pairs.txt`), specifically what criteria
are supposed to be used to determine uniqueness. Just the question text, the
question and answer text, or something else?

So I'll focus on a few suggestions for an easier way to read the input data.
You current code is repetitive, with similar calls to `rstrip()` and `len()`
lurking in various if-else branches. None of that is needed. Similarly, your
code is complicated by the fact that you are storing the questions and answers
in separate lists. But the data are inherently related: each question pairs
with an answer. So, under most conditions, storing the data in a unified way
will make more sense. In this sketch, I'll use a list of `(question, answer)`
tuples. Finally, why bother removing the leading `question` and `answer`
prefixes on each line if the output files are supposed to have the same format?
Just leave the text alone for the most part.

```
def overlapping_pairs():
    # Read the Q-A pairs.
    with open('QA_Pairs.txt') as fh:
        pairs = []
        while True:
            q = next(fh, '').rstrip()
            a = next(fh, '').rstrip()
            if q:
                pairs.append((q, a))
            else:
                break

    # Usage illustration.
    for q, a in pairs:
        print(q)
        print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    overlapping_pairs()
```

If you ultimately need to check for uniqueness of something, that list of
question-answer pairs will be easy to work with. Alternatively, you can retain
the core idea (store related questions and answers together, not apart) but
select a different data structure. For example, one might end up with a dict
keyed by the question text, where each value is a list of answers. That would
tell you which questions are unique (or non-unique) and each unique question
would be linked to all related answers.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestion